# Synchronizing files on local network NAS in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, winscp, winscp-net

I want to one-way synchronize all folders in my `C:\Apps` directory into my backup directory of my **NAS** `\\192.168.1.20\Sebastian\Backup` by my WPF/C# application.

I chose WinSCP for this job:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#csharp

The example (see link) does not help. I do not know which protocol I should use.

```
var sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = @"\\192.168.1.20",
    UserName = "Sebastian",
    Password = "MyNasPassword"
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Will continuously report progress of synchronization
    session.FileTransferred += FileTransferred;

    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Synchronize files
    SynchronizationResult synchronizationResult;
    synchronizationResult = session.SynchronizeDirectories
       (SynchronizationMode.Remote, @"C:\Apps", @"\\192.168.1.20\Sebastian\Backup", true);

    // Throw on any error
    synchronizationResult.Check();
}
```

I get only the error (in line: `session.Open(sessionOptions)`;
)

> Connection failed

Comment: "\\192.168.1.20" is how you write the address in Explorer, but the server address is just "192.168.1.20" without the "\\" at the start. Have you tried that?

Comment: Then I get this error: Connection failed: Unable to connect because the destination computer refused to connect

Comment: Is your NAS running a FTP server? When you connect using Windows Explorer, you probably connect over SMB (windows file sharing), not FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinSCP can work only over FTP, SFTP and other similar protocols. While you want to synchronize files over local network (not FTP despite your code). That’s not something that WinSCP can to.

Though most NAS do support FTP or SFTP. Maybe you need to enable it first though.